# How to handle tokens when one is subset of another in Antlr?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to port an existing grammar developed for an unknown tool to Antlr. 
There is a use case in the grammar where there are two tokens such as TEXT and TEXT_WITHOUT_A
Some rules in the grammar should allow only text without a, but the rest is OK with using text.

My initial attempts produced the following grammar, but the problem is, Antlr matches the more specific grammar rule (txtwa) when txt is actually a superset of it. If I enter something like 'sometextwth' that does not contain a, Antlr does not follow the rule for text (txt) The expected input is txt, and the provided input matches is, but Antlr figures out that the input matches txtwa and even if it is not expected at that point in grammar, chooses not to use txt.

```
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 expr   :   (  txt)* ;
 txt    :   TEXT ;
 txtwa  :   LETTERS_MINUS_A;
 term   :   factor ( (MULT | DIV) factor)*;
 factor :   NUMBER;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/


NUMBER              :   (DIGIT)+ ;

WHITESPACE      :   ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;} ;

fragment LETTER_MINUS_A :   ('b'..'z' | 'B'..'Z');

fragment LETTER :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');


fragment DIGIT      :   '0'..'9' ;   



LETTERS_MINUS_A 
    :   LETTER_MINUS_A (LETTER_MINUS_A)*;       

TEXT    :   LETTER (LETTER)* ;
```

I'd like to use txt freely without having to do (txt | txtwa) , which works btw. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must realize that the lexer does not take into account what the parser needs at a particular time: it simply tries to construct a token going through the lexer rules from top to bottom.

Because you defined `LETTERS_MINUS_A` before `TEXT`, `LETTERS_MINUS_A` will always be created instead of `TEXT`, which will only ever contain `'a'`'s and `'A'`'s.

This is simply how ANTLR works.

What you *can* do is simply throw away the `LETTERS_MINUS_A` rule and do something like this:

```
txt
 : TEXT 
 ;

txtwa 
 : TEXT 
   {
     if($TEXT.text.contains("a") || $TEXT.text.contains("A")) {
       throw new Exception("Eeek, I saw an `[aA]`!");
     }
   }
 ;
```

Comment: I have sections in the original grammar where txt and txtwa are used on their own. I simply need txt and txtwa, where txtwa is just one letter less than txt. I'll have to use both.

Comment: You have given the right answer, it is just that I've failed to see that you're using the parser rules section. Thanks, this really helped.